# What is a 'civic institution'?

Tags: meaning

The term appears in the *International New York Times*: ["Radical Pope, Traditional Values"](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/12/30/opinion/radical-pope-traditional-values.html?pagewanted=2&_r=1&hp&rref=opinion):

> As a result of its work in basic health and education — and despite its obtuse views on birth control — in the last 50 years the church has probably lifted more people out of poverty than any other civic institution in history.

Internet (I forgot where) suggests that a 'civic institution' by definition cannot be a government (or a market participant). However, we also have

> **civic** Of, relating to, or belonging to a city, a citizen, or citizenship; municipal or civil.

and

> **civil** (not comparable) Having to do with people and government office as opposed to the military or religion.

This could be construed as *excluding* the Catholic Church (and *including* government).

So, what, if any, is a good definition of 'civic institution'? Or is the term ambiguous?

Comment: It's ambiguous, or rather, imprecise. In a particular piece of writing, the writing may use it in a precise way, but there are other interpretations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the inclusion of the word *other* which implies that the Church is a civic institution. However, the word *other* is used because the formula is more-or-less fixed: *than any other X* is commonly heard, probably more often than *than any X*.

The Church does share some of the aspects of a civic institution because it does the work of one: it alleviates poverty and provides assistance to those in need. In some countries it provides facilities which are provided by the State elsewhere: social care, hospitals, orphanages, education and so on. Does this make it a civic institution? Possibly, if you define *civic* to mean *for the citizen* or something similar.

Thus, if one considers the geography where the Church is most active in providing those services, it probably does class as a civic institution. It may sound odd to those in countries where Church and State are constitutionally separated or where the government customarily provides such social support.